# Consumable channel

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

#### Use Case

Android fragment that consumes items of `T` from a `ReceiveChannel<T>`. Once consumed, the `T`s should be removed from the `ReceiveChannel<T>`.

I need a `ReceiveChannel<T>` that supports consuming items from it. It should function as a FIFO queue.

I currently attach to the channel from my UI like:

```
launch(uiJob) { channel.consumeEach{ /** ... */ } }
```

I detach by calling `uiJob.cancel()`.

Desired behavior:

```
val channel = Channel<Int>(UNLIMITED)

channel.send(1)
channel.send(2)
// ui attaches, receives `1` and `2`
channel.send(3) // ui immediately receives `3`
// ui detaches
channel.send(4)
channel.send(5)
// ui attaches, receiving `4` and `5`
```

Unfortunately, when I detach from the channel, the channel is closed. This causes `.send(4)` and `.send(5)` to throw exceptions because the channel is closed. I want to be able to detach from the channel and have it remain usable. How can I do this?

`Channel<Int>(UNLIMITED)` fits my use case perfect, *except* that is closes the channel when it is unsubscribed from. I want the channel to remain open. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Channel.consumeEach` method calls `Channel.consume` method which has this line in documentation:

> Makes sure that the given block consumes all elements from the given channel **by always invoking cancel after the execution of the block**.

So the solution is to simply not use `consume[Each]`. For example you can do:

`launch(uiJob) { for (it in channel) { /** ... */ } }`

Comment: this works. The downside here is that the receiver can close the channel, which is not desired behavior

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I expected `ReceiveChannel<E>` to be read-only, but it's not! Being able to close it makes it mutable

Comment: I guess you can wrap it in another interface without close method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BroadcastChannel`. However, you need to specify a limited size (such as `1`), as `UNLIMITED` and `0` (for rendez-vous) are not supported by `BroadcastChannel`.

You can also use `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` which always gives the latest value it had to new subscribers, like `LiveData` is doing.

BTW, is it a big deal if you new `Fragment` instance receives only the latest value? If not, then just go with `ConflatedBroadcastChannel`. Otherwise, none of `BroacastChannel`s may suit your use case (try it and see if you get the behavior you're looking for).

Comment: I have a `ConflatedBroadcastChannel<ViewState>` already. Need a "consumable" channel to send side effects to the UI like showing a toast or vibrating the device

Comment: You can add a `markHandled()` function to your `ViewState` that flips a `hasBeenHandled` boolean property that is publicly read-only, and before trying to handle the event, you check it hasn't been handled already with an if.